# ADColony video ad crashes the app due to orientation change

Tags: ios, swift, adcolony

First time when I play ADColony ad it appears all fine but again second time when I play the ad it did not occupy the whole screen and after I closed the ad the app crashed with the log saying :

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and [ADCRotatingViewController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES'

My app is coded in swift and it returns shouldAutorotate() as false and the supported orientations are UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue | UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft.rawValue

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return false
    }

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
        return UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue | UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft.rawValue
    }
```

Please help me regarding this isssue.

Comment: I know this is old, but this may help others. Try setting the supported orientations of the app to be portrait and landscape in the target's General > Deployment Info > Device Orientation for this not to fail. In the (root) view controller make sure that your supported orientations are still portrait. Also, this is NOT fixed in AdColony's latest version (2.6.0). There's also the issue where the device rotates 2-3 times before rotating correctly back to portrait from landscape after a video plays. It is a horrid user experience. Apps in locked portrait mode do not work out of the box on iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're integrating with an old version of our SDK. Please try updating with the latest available version at http://github.com/adcolony. If that doesn't solve your issue, please submit a support ticket to support@adcolony.com.

Comment: adcolony video is playing only in full screen, how to play video in some of the portion of screen?

Comment: This is not available as for now, you need to display the full screen ads only.